# same css position different results in diff browsers

Tags: css

How is it possible that there is a 3 px difference in the vertical position of textfields in a form when seen in those 3 diff. browsers?

I am going insane. It is not good trying to fix it in the CSS because if I change it, it is fine in one but not in the others.

```
#pricefromR 

{width:75px;
position:relative;
right:40px;
top: 50px;
}

#pricetoR 

{width:75px;
position:relative;
right:-45px;
top: 24px;
}
```

So this corresponds to two texfields which are supposed to be paralell, at the same leve with each other, but they are not in different browsers, by a difference of 3 px and it happens the same with the other pairs which are each in a LI

```
<li>
        <input type ="text" id = "areafromR" placeholder="area from" name = "areafrom" maxlength = "5">&nbsp;
        <input type ="text" id = "areatoR" placeholder="area to" name = "areato" maxlength = "5">
    </li>
```

Comment: It is probably to do with browser default margins, padding and borders. Try setting `{ margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }` on related elements and hopefully you can narrow it down.

Comment: Show us the rest of your code please: HTML, other relevant CSS

Comment: Can you replicate this in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

All browsers are different, they have different defaults, and different wu=idths/heights. The best way that I know of is to either use percents, but that can get complicated. You can make a the CSS seperate for different browsers. For example ...... That is for internet explorer

Answer (score -2):

You should try to [reset your CSS](https://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

> In case you didn’t know, every browser has its own default ‘user
>   agent’ stylesheet, that it uses to make unstyled websites appear more
>   legible. For example, most browsers by default make links blue and
>   visited links purple, give tables a certain amount of border and
>   padding, apply variable font-sizes to H1, H2, H3 etc. and a certain
>   amount of padding to almost everything. Ever wondered why Submit
>   buttons look different in every browser? It limits the difference
>   between browsers

Using a CSS Reset, you can force every browser to have all its styles reset to null, so less cross-browser differences

With this code:

```
/**
* Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
* http://cssreset.com
*/
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
```

A common practice is to put this in another CSS file.

Comment: This is a terrible answer to a simple question. It's like using a shotgun when a scalpel would have sufficed. This bloats your computed styles with inherited properties that simply need not be inherited. Browser defaults, while they may differ slightly, are *not that different*. There is a W3C recommended default, which most browsers adhere to.

Comment: Well, I don't see why we shouldn't reset our CSS. It's the first thing I do when I start a new project. It's an easy copy/paste that solves a lot of problems.  This one is made by Eric Meyer and it's one of the most popular CSS reset. I don't see why it would be a bad practice. Actually,it's one of the first thing I learned when I started HTML/CSS

Comment: Even Mr. Meyer recommends that you don't use his reset *verbatim*. It should be customized to what *you need*. This brings it much closer to *CSS normalization*, which is far better practice than resets. My main point, though, is that it makes debugging your CSS *absolute hell*. Every element will have not only the styles directly applied to it, but styles inherited from its parents as well. Inspecting these elements becomes a non-trivial task, as does determining the interaction between styles.

Comment: In addition, I've found many cases where a particular style is obliterated in the reset file, and then re-applied in a different file. I've seen many cases that are much worse than that as well (including unfortunate renderings of bulleted lists that I won't discuss). In my opinion, working *with* the default styles is far preferable to working *against* them.

Comment: Well, it's up to you to make your own reset file. It saved me a lot of time and I'm convinced it's a good practice. And I'm sure it good for the OP to consider using one.